# Failing to run DOM (with cURL)

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm trying to replace a working Simple DOM HTML Parser snippet with another one in order to send a cookie.. Problem is that it just screws my page up.

I am trying to get the description text from the game, which is within a div by the `class game_description_snippet`. That particular div only contains text and no other tags.

Non-working:

```
//Not working at all
$url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/100";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "birthtime=28801; path=/; domain=store.steampowered.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new domDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($result);

$descrs = $dom->getElementsByClassName('game_description_snippet');
foreach ($descrs as $descr) {
    $spanx = $descr->textContent;
    echo $spanx;
}
```

Trying to replace the following code with it and add that cookie:

```
//Working, but slowly.
$url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/100";
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('div.game_description_snippet') as $element) {

    if(empty($element)) {
        $descr = "This link will take you to the full game.";
    } else {
        $unformatted = $element->plaintext;
        $formatted = trim($unformatted);
        $descr = str_replace("'", "", $formatted);
        if($descr == "<br>") {
            $descr == "";
        }
    }
}
```

Just a little guidance would be much appreciated. I know I'm a newb and so, but I've been Googling around for hours and I don't know how to move on. I did make a similar function work, but it didn't contain the cURL part and ran by just using `$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);` instead..

EDIT:

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    $knas = $span->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $knas;
}
```

This worked for me, but then the result didn't contain only text (which it does in my current case), it contained something like `<h1>Some text</h1>`

Comment: "not working" does not tell us anything. please be explicit about what exactly is "not working." are you getting an error.. ? the fact that you're here tells us it's not working. please tell us what it *is* doing.

Comment: @Pamblam Sorry. Whatever comes underneath that part, and everything in the div it's wrapped within is erased. It does not echo `$spanx`, it does not echo anything from `<div class="game_description_snippet"></div>`

Comment: (as far as I can see)

Comment: if its not echoing anything it sounds like a 500. try my suggestion below, if that doesn't fix it, please put this at the very top of your PHP file, underneath the opening  `<?php` ....`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", "1");` ..that should give you the error message, then you can paste it here and we'll be able to see what's wrong.

Comment: @Pamblam Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Empty string supplied as input in (line 95). Line 95 is: `$dom->loadHTMLFile($result);`

Comment: @Pamblam I'm sure the url is valid.

Comment: @Pamblam also: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementsByClassName(). I'm not sure why that's not working either..

Comment: you were right about the cookie. i should have checked the manual myself before answering :P

Comment: Well there's one problem. use `$dom->loadHTML($result);` since you're passing it a string instead of a file.

Comment: however, that is only part of the problem since you're curl page is retuning an empty string.

Comment: Since `$result` does not only contain only an URL? Hmm.. I guess I could use just loadHTMLFile and live without the cookie, but I'm still not sure how to get only the text from the div. I've previously used `$span->item(0)->nodeValue;`, but then `$span` not contain only text

Comment: can you try to post your code in 3v4l.org and then post the link to it? i'm not even sure if 3v4l supports curl but worth a shot.. at least i'll be able to see your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100623/discussion-between-john-smith-and-pamblam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in chat, you need to have the PHP request a cookie rather that sending one you got from your browser. The server will validate the cookie and if it's not coming from the same session it won't be a valid cookie.

Here's the code that I got to work.

```
// Modified the cURL function to accept POST parameters and a cookiejar file
// You will actually need to use a cookie jar because the cookie is not static
// Using a cookie jar allows the server  to change the cookie as needed and the changed cookie is sent back to the server.
function request($url, $params=array(), $cookiejar="") {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlOpts = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
    );
    if (!empty($params)) {
        // If POST values are given, send that shit too
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params;
    }
    if (!empty($cookiejar)) {

        if(!file_exists($cookiejar)){
            echo 'Cookie file missing. please create it first.'; exit;
        }else if(!is_writable($cookiejar)){
            echo 'Cookie file not writable. chmod it to 777.'; exit;
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookiejar));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($cookiejar));
    }
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
    $answer = curl_exec($ch);
    // If there was an error, show it
    if (curl_error($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $answer;
}

// The url you're trying to access
$url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/223470";

// The url that gives  us the cookie
$cookie_url = "http://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/223470/";

// The POST parameters that are sent to the server when requesting a cookie
$params = array("ageDay"=>1, "ageMonth"=>"January", "ageYear"=>"1915", "snr"=>"1_agecheck_agecheck__age-gate");

// This request just give us a cookie.
request($cookie_url, $params, "cookiejar");

// And this request is that page you need
$html =  request($url, array(), "cookiejar");

// Domdoc stuff that we already discussed
$dom = new domDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$classname="game_description_snippet";
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$spaner = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

foreach ($spaner as $spane) { 
    $mo = $spane->nodeValue;
    echo $mo;
}
```